# Select Image from group of images

Tags: html

I want the user to be able to **select an image from a set of images**. I want to do it in a way that is a) both part of a form element and b) works well for older browsers/browsers without javascript enabled.

I thought about overwriting the css to make a set of `radio buttons` display the images, but that looks like it's really hard to hide the bullet.

Another option was to overwrite the css in an `option...select` structure to display images, but that only worked on some browsers.

Is there any easy way to do this? Or should I create two options: one for browsers with Javascript and one for browsers without?

Answer (score 3):

You could make the image part of a `<label>` for each radio button, and hide the radio button with `visibility: hidden` or something.

```
<label>
    <img src="image1.png" alt="Some image" />
    <input type="radio" name="image" value="1" />
</label>
```

… come to think of it, that’s pretty much the only way you can give a radio button an image, and it should work as expected. (Unless you were going to use `background-image`?)

Answer (score 0):

Provided you set `appearance:none` hiding the bullet, showing the images semantically *as options* is as easy as styling any other element to be an image (eg via `background-image`).

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/Hashbrown/pen/eYXKoQp)